# How to deal with 2 submit buttons in one form in struts2

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2

I am developing an application using struts2. I was stuck at a point, where I have 2 buttons, in a single struts2 form. I want one of the buttons, not to call the default form action bean, despite call its own Jquery modal dialog based on this button ID. Each time I click the button, its calling the form action bean. How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a Jquery function for button2 using button id as a reference. This function is called upon clicking that. I have placed the below line of code in the first line of that function.

```
$('#button2id').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The above line of code prevents calling the default form action, i.e.., struts2 action bean.

Answer (score 2):

On form submit don't call action directly.

On clicking submit button call a JavaScript method and then inside method control the behavior.

```
<script>
  /*
   function doSomething() {
    alert('Form submitted!');
    //perform your expected behavior
  } */
  function fun1(){
     //perform operation
  }
  function fun2(){
     //perform operation
  }
</script>

<form id="formid">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit1" onclick="fun1();">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit2" onclick="fun2();">
</form>
```